# Linux doesn't boot when HP HBA controller is connected

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hp-smart-array, proxmox, hba

I have an HP H240 Smart HBA. On Windows 10, it works without a problem, but any Linux I tested refuses to boot with a connected controller.

Platform: AMD B450 (AM4, various processors)
List of tested Linux distributions: Ubuntu Server 20.04, Ubuntu Desktop 20.04, Debian 10 (PVE), Linux Mint 20.

The error is approximately as follows:

```
[0.316237] __common_interrupt: 2.55 No irq handler for vector
[0.316237] __common_interrupt: 3.55 No irq handler for vector
[0.316237] __common_interrupt: 4.55 No irq handler for vector
[0.316237] __common_interrupt: 5.55 No irq handler for vector
[0.316237] __common_interrupt: 6.55 No irq handler for vector
[0.316237] __common_interrupt: 7.55 No irq handler for vector
[0.316237] __common_interrupt: 8.55 No irq handler for vector
[0.316237] __common_interrupt: 9.55 No irq handler for vector
[0.316237] __common_interrupt: 10.55 No irq handler for vector
[0.950739] nouveau 0000:07:00.0: DRM: core notifier timeout
```

Comment: Are you actually using an HPE server? This smells like a BIOS bug, and Linux tends to be less forgiving of such bugs than Windows.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I am using a desktop motherboard with Ryzen on b450(In Windows 10 work good).

Comment: Can you try editing grub boot arguments: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pci=nomsi,noaer"`?

Comment: @Marco Unfortunately, this did not work. Tried earlier

Comment: @Zaken what about acpi=noirq? In anyway Michael is probably right. Try updating all firmwares and also the BIOS. Also update to the latest kernel.

Comment: That includes updating the firmware on the HBA card.

Comment: After some tests, I realized that the controller works without errors on Ubuntu 14.04, but i am using Debian 10 / ubuntu 20.04. No idea how to solve this problem.